# How do I make a selectize.js select box require a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

My original select box has the `required` attribute set

```
<select name="some-name" value="initialValue" required>
     <option value="initialValue">initial value</option>
     <option value="otherValue">other value</option>
</select>
```

I start selectize:

```
$("select[name='some-name']").selectize()
```

But users can still use the backspace key to remove the selected option, making the select box have a value of `''`.

Since `required` on the real select box doesn't seem to affect Selectize, I've read [the selectize documentation](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) but can't find any way to stop users from deleting the option.

**How can I prevent users from setting the value to anything except a valid option?**

Comment: It looks like that's a feature of this plugin: `Selectize is the hybrid of a textbox and <select> box. `. I recently used jQuery Selectric which may be a better choice if you are looking just for customized style (I haven't tested with required attribute). Are you using this only to customize the dropdown, or do you need the textbox functionality?

Comment: @brouxhaha I use selectize's textbox functionality elsewhere (for other elements) so alas switching out from selectize (and having two select replacements) isn't practical.

Comment: Gah! Well... have you tried working with the `onDelete(values)` callback function? Maybe you can either prevent it from doing anything or just set the value to the current selected value?

Comment: You can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582558/selectizejs-disable-remove-on-backspace-or-remove-ibeam-entirely

Comment: Thanks @alemv, that approach is working - I've thrown demo code into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* check to see if the selected options are less than 1 when removing an option, if it is add the item back. getValue() returns an array of currently selected values.

To the user it just looks like its undeletable or not removable.

```
var userSelectize = $(...).selectize({});
userSelectize[0].selectize.on("item_remove", function(value, item) {
            if (userSelectize[0].selectize.getValue().length < 1) {
                this.addItem(value);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selectize no-delete](https://github.com/akrikos/selectize-no-delete) works fine. Since I use npm:

```
var Selectize = require('selectize');

// https://github.com/akrikos/selectize-no-delete/blob/master/src/selectize-no-delete.js
Selectize.define('no-delete', function(options) {
  this.deleteSelection = function() {};
});
```

Then, when you make a selectize instance:

```
$("select[name='country-code']").selectize({
    plugins: {
        'no-delete': {}
    },
    ....
})
```